# Custom AlertDialog how to access android.R.id.custom

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to know how to access this R.id.custom framelayout from [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog)
[image]
If I have this code

```kotlin
class CustomDialogFragment3(context: Context) : DialogFragment() {

    private val builder: MaterialAlertDialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        builder.setTitle("Custom Dialog")
        builder.setMessage("content")
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", object: DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
            }
        })

        val fl: FrameLayout = this.requireView().findViewById(android.R.id.custom) <---- throw error

        val inflater = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_image, fl, false)
        fl.addView(myView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT))
        return builder.create()
    }

}
```

It throws IllegalStateException, it always throw this exception even after I move this code inside the positiveButtonClick.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alertdialogcustom, PID: 25607
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CustomDialogFragment3{8095c6e} (926fe9e3-d9ea-460a-b413-5b678827681a tag=TAG3) did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireView(Fragment.java:1964)
```

I know there is also setView() method on the builder, but I am just interested why I am getting this error and what is the right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `CustomDialogFragment3` isn't going to return a `View` from `onCreateView()` because you're handling it all through the `Dialog` creation. That's perfectly fine, but you can't call `requireView()`, 'cause that throws if `onCreateView()` returns null. That's not where you'd want to look, anyway. You would want to call `findViewById()` on the `Dialog` sometime after it's created. However, it looks like you don't really even need to do that. Can't you just call `setView(R.layout.layout_image)` on the `builder`?

Comment: Ignore the last sentences of my comment above. I didn't notice that you'd mentioned you were aware of that.